# Python - ffmpeg (commands to start, stop recording)

Tags: python, cmd, ffmpeg, command

I need a programme that would open cmd and have a command to start recording in cmd and to stop recording in cmd

```
import win32com.client
from datetime import datetime
import time

shell = win32com.client.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")
shell.run("cmd") #run's command panel
shell.AppActivate("cmd")
time.sleep(3) #wait's 3 seconds
shell.SendKeys('ffmpeg -y -f dshow -i video="Logitech HD Webcam C270"  
kamera.mp4') #type's in cmd the following (start's recording)
time.sleep(3)
shell.SendKeys("{ENTER}") #enter is pressed in cmd
time.sleep(6)
shell.SendKeys('exit')
shell.SendKeys("{ENTER}") #here is a problem, the proggrame wont shutdown after 6 sec
```

I could use -t 00:00:03 in ffmpeg, but I need to close the programme by command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I already cracked that on my own, if anyone needs the code here it is:

```
import win32com.client
from datetime import datetime
import time

datestring = datetime.strftime(datetime.now(), '%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S')
shell = win32com.client.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")

shell.run("cmd")
shell.AppActivate("cmd")

#shell.run('ffmpeg -y -f dshow -i video="Logitech HD Webcam C270"  kamera' + datestring + '.mp4')
time.sleep(2)
shell.SendKeys('ffmpeg -y -f dshow -i video="Logitech HD Webcam C270"  kamera.mp4')
time.sleep(2)
shell.SendKeys("{ENTER}")
time.sleep(10)
shell.SendKeys('^c')
time.sleep(2)
shell.SendKeys("{ENTER}")
```